# how to concentrate two variables in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub action here which looks somewhat like this:

```
jobs:
  build-and-push-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        include:
          - dockerfile: ./web/Dockerfile
            image: ghcr.io/user/redwood-docker-compose-web
            appname: web
          - dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
            image: ghcr.io/user/redwood-docker-compose-api
            appname: api

    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Get branch name
        id: branch-name
        uses: tj-actions/branch-names@v6
      # .... do a lot of stuf
      - name: Deploy image
        uses: floms/action-caprover@v1
        with:
          host: '${{ secrets.CAPROVER_SERVER }}'
          password: '${{ secrets.CAPROVER_PASSWORD }}'
          app: join(${{ id }}${{ matrix.appname }})
          image: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
```

the second last line makes some Problems for me:
since this is a matrix operation I need individual names here. what i want to achieve is that app is once for example mainweb and mainapi (so [branchname][appname])

how would I concentrate these two strings here:

```
join(${{ id }}${{ matrix.appname }})
```

one problem is, that I get the error message that id is not recognized. the second is (probably) that join does not work here.

What's the right way?

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: Concatenate? And what were you expecting `id` to be?

Comment: sorry, i should have read the man page... ```${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}``` gives me the current branch. i need to find a way to make one string out of the two strings so this should be one: ```${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}${{ matrix.appname }}```

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly. I'd expect that to _work_.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for that missleading question... joining two strings just works:

this:

```
app: join(${{ id }}${{ matrix.appname }})
```

just needs to be

```
app: ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}${{ matrix.appname }}
```

no join() or whatever is needed...